# Upload an image from mobile web app (PhoneGap & JavaScript) to a SOAP web service returns status 0

Tags: javascript, soap, xmlhttprequest

I have seen many examples and forums but it's not yet clear for me.
I want to take a picture with a mobile then send it to the WebService.
In the WebService I have a function `UploadImage` that saves the image in a website. The parameters of this function are:

```
 <UploadImage xmlns="http://*********">
  <urlSite>http://********</urlSite>
  <iListName>{*************}</iListName>
  <iUpdateMode>*******</iUpdateMode>
  <iMetaData><Fields><Field Name=”Title” >Title of the Image</Field></Fields></iMetaData>
  <iAttachments><Attachments><Attachment Name=”Name of the file”>file in the format Base64String</Attachment></Attachments></iAttachments>
  <iOverWrite>****</iOverWrite>
</UploadImage>
```

The post request:

```
function sendImage ()
{
    var wsUrl = "*******?op=UploadImage";
    var soapRequest ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" \
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
  <soap:Body> \
    <UploadImage xmlns="**********"> \
      <urlSite>**********</urlSite> \
      <iListName>{******}</iListName> \
      <iUpdateMode>********</iUpdateMode> \
      <iMetaData><Fields><Field Name=”Title” >Title of the Image</Field></Fields></iMetaData>
      <iAttachments><Attachments><Attachment Name=”Name of the file”>file in the format Base64String</Attachment></Attachments></iAttachments> \
      <iOverWrite>*****</iOverWrite> \
    </UploadImage> \
  </soap:Body> \
</soap:Envelope>';
    var xmlhttp =  createXMLHttpRequest();


xmlhttp.open("POST", wsUrl, true,"username","password");

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader ("Post", "********");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader ("Host", "*****");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader ("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", soapRequest.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader ("SOAPAction", "******");


xmlhttp.onerror = function(e) {
    alert("Error ocurred. Error = " + e.message);
}

xmlhttp.ontimeout = function(e) {
    alert("Timeout error!");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = function () { 
    alert(xmlhttp.readyState);

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        alert(xmlhttp.status);
        // if "OK"
        if (xmlhttp.status==200 || xmlhttp.status==0)
        {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseXML);
        //[Get xmlhttp.responseXML.xml and do something with it]

        }
        else
        {
        //[Get xmlhttp.responseXML.xml and do something with it in the case of an error]
        }
    }
}


xmlhttp.send(soapRequest);
```

}

The status t=returned is 0.
In the tag `<iAttachments><Attachments><Attachment Name=”Name of the file”>file in the format Base64String</Attachment></Attachments></iAttachments>` I should send a file in a Base64 format, but I don't know how to put a file in this format in this tag, so I send a String, maybe it's a cause of the problem!

I have tried to post it with jquery.ajax:

```
function sendReq()
{    var wsUrl = "*******";
    var soapRequest ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
  '<soap:Body>'+
    '<UpdateImage xmlns="*******">'+
      '<urlSite>*********</urlSite>'+
      '<iListName>{*****}</iListName>'+
      '<iUpdateMode>****</iUpdateMode>'+
      '<iMetaData><Fields><Field Name="Title" >'+my_var1+'</Field></Fields></iMetaData>'+
      '<iAttachments><Attachments><Attachment Name="Nom du fichier 1">'+my_var2+'</Attachment></Attachments></iAttachments>'+
      '<iOverWrite>*****</iOverWrite>'+
    '</UpdateImage>'+
  '</soap:Body>'+
'</soap:Envelope>';
   $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: wsUrl,
                    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: soapRequest,
                    beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth('username', 'password')); 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "****/UpdateImage");
    },                
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",

                success: processSuccess,
                error: processError
            });
return false;
```

}

the result is: `req.responseText=undefined` and `status=error`

Answer (score 0):

I would base64 encode a file with some online tool (eg http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/) and hard code the string into your xml. See if that works first to check the rest of your code is fine.

If that works then check out this question for how to base64 encode your file before you send it:
[Get Base64 encode file-data from Input Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978156/get-base64-encode-file-data-from-input-form)

Also - a debugging proxy is very useful in this situation so you can see the actual request being sent. If you have something that already works with this service you can use something like fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) to grab the request and compare it to yours.