# Upload/Load image through HTML, and Display on JS Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, uploading

i'm quite new in the interaction between JS and Html and I'd like to know if it is possible to Upload an image through an HTML (a button or dropping it), and Display on JS Canvas so that I can modify it through Javascript pure, no jQuery.

So I can for example call the image like this: Image(img, 0, 0).. add a background or a point on it when the mouse is pressed.

I know that what I'm asking, and how I'm asking, can sound silly, but as i said I'm new in this subject.

I will appreciate any kind of help, as for example a link to similars question.

Thanks

Giovanni

Comment: Post what you have done so far.

Comment: check this out [stackoverflow: javascript-upload-image-file-and-draw-it-into-a-canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255580/javascript-upload-image-file-and-draw-it-into-a-canvas)

Comment: But still the image is shown on the html canvas, how could i like add a point on the Image through Javascript ? I'm in: draw the image through javascript  Function Draw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript: upload image file and draw it into a canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255580/javascript-upload-image-file-and-draw-it-into-a-canvas)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you could try something like this ...

```js
var fileUpload = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
var canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function readImage() {
    if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
           var img = new Image();
           img.src = e.target.result;
           img.onload = function() {
             ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 512, 512);
           };
        };       
        FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
    }
}

fileUpload.onchange = readImage;

canvas.onclick = function(e) {
  var x = e.offsetX;
  var y = e.offsetY;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fill();
};
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type='file' id="fileUpload"/>
<canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
```

Answer (score -1):

The link to the original post:  [stackoverflow: javascript-upload-image-file-and-draw-it-into-a-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255580/javascript-upload-image-file-and-draw-it-into-a-canvas)

**Code:**

```js
function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);} // Get elem by ID

var canvas  = el("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function readImage() {
    if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
           var img = new Image();
           img.onload = function() {
             context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
           };
           img.src = e.target.result;
        };       
        FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
    }
}

el("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
```

```html
<input type='file' id="fileUpload" />
<canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi Thank you so much, i won't upload what i did for now cause it's embarassing,
But still the image is shown on the html canvas, how could i like add a a point on the Image through Javascript ?

Comment: see [stackoverflow: drawing-a-dot-on-html5-canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812514/drawing-a-dot-on-html5-canvas)
You're already getting the context of the canvas in `context ` variable.

Comment: So, once I choose the file, there is no way to preload it and then showing it through the function draw [image(img, 0, 0] like if I had preloaded it in the assets folder ??!

Comment: I'd like to work on it through the JS language not through HTML