# Rounded corners on rectangular image using CSS only

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a round image from a rectangular image using radius-border.

Is there simple way to achieve this with CSS without distorting the image AND ensuring a circle is perfectly round.

See failed attempts here:

http://jsfiddle.net/v8g3y0na/

```
.rounded-corners-2{
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
```

Can this be done in only CSS.....?

Comment: Noting from your fiddle that you are trying to fit a rectangular image into a circle.  Which bit of the image do you want to lose?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You do that by adding a parent div to your img and the code flows as follows

```
figure{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/4qyv8ort/)

Comment: the issue here is that the image isn't centered in the circle.

Comment: Yep it works like that it actually crops the img to by inheriting the size of your parent div.

Comment: @web-tiki you can position your img follow this link http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/v8g3y0na/7/

Comment: The technique you are using to center the image in the container won't work for all images. If they have different widths, it will fail.

Comment: Updated the url @mbomb007

Answer (score 29):

### Round image using CSS `object-fit` and border radius:

```css
img{
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/800/400">
```

### `img` with background image

For older browsers, using the `<img>` tag

```html
<img alt="My image" 
 src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
     style="background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1011/300/180) 50% / cover; 
            border-radius: 50%;
            width:150px;">
```

The trick is to set a transparent px for the `src` (to prevent *broken image* icon) and do the best CSS3 and background-size has to offer (`cover`).

Comment: I've read through all the answers on this page and this is by far the smartest! Its also the most compact. And it uses no javascript! And it uses no css! Thanks @Roko C. Buljan! What image does it contain here? With which tool do you convert the graphic into base64 code? Thanks +1!

Comment: Thanks! Well, it actually uses CSS as you can see `style="` which is ofc best put into a separate stylesheet :) To convert an image to base64 you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17711190/383904 .

Comment: @mbomb007 yep, it exists (perhaps yesterday the server was down) - Anyways, the code matters here - one can always use it's own image, but thanks for reporting - now you can delete your comment...

Answer (score 13):

> *Is there simple way to achieve this with CSS without distorting the image AND ensuring a circle is perfectly round.*

Yes, and you can also avoid using parent elements by just setting the image as the background. You can also position the image as you wish by using the `background-position` attribute.

Updated to address concerns about size, roundness, skewing and dynamically loaded content.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
 $("#image").css("background-image", "url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97350&w=150&h=350)");
}, 3000);
```

```css
#image {
    display: block;
    background-image: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150");
    border-radius: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" />
```

Comment: yes this works if the width and height are same unless it will skew

Comment: @Benjamin How else is one supposed to make a circle if the width and height aren't the same? It's the same as your example but without using a parent div.

Comment: dude we can make a img a circle when we sizes a non-linear for instance if the image in 300X200 when we are abt to size it looks like skewed. I think you know wat im speaking abt. No offense here

Comment: The image is in the background, it doesn't matter what are the dimensions of the image, it's never distorted.

Comment: im not mentioning abt the background here and i didn't even downvote you. I accept what you did i'm just mention abt img src dude.

Comment: That's why I suggested putting the image in the background and not in the `src` attribute of the `img` element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59208/discussion-between-benjamin-and-arielnmz).

Comment: @arielnmz...and how would you use this approach if the page and images are generated dynamically? I don't think you can. I know the OP wasn't asking that but I am looking to do that.

Comment: I assume you are using some sort of scripting for the dynamic content, in that case just change the background-image property of the element. Easy.

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/o8fwpug5/37/

This is a slight update of a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25267963/1811992). I liked the other answer, but this is a bit more streamlined and gives a pixel based width for the wrapper. This way it is easier to see and change the dimensions for your own purposes.

HTML:

```
<div><img src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg" /></div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    position:relative;    
    border-radius:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img{
    position:absolute;
    left:-50%; right:-50%; top:0;
    margin:auto;
    height:100%; width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a DIV frame around the image: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/v8g3y0na/5/)**

```
<div class="rounded-corners">
   <img src="http://welovekaleycuoco.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Kaley-Cuoco-Wallpapers-81.jpg" width="200"> 
</div>

div.rounded-corners {     
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

*note: you don't need your img.rounded-corners style anymore*