# How to make a round img using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a 50% rounded img inside a simple div. I have tried 2 ways to do it, but obviously neither has worked for me.
If it makes something clear, the image, that I'm getting is square

```
/*HTML*/

<div class="img-container"></div>

/*CSS*/
.img-container {
    background: url("../../../../../assets/img/user-photo.svg") no-repeat center top / cover;
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }


/*HTML*/

<div class="img-container">
    <img src="path_to_img" alt="User photo">
</div>

/*CSS*/

.img-container {
     width: 125px;
     height: 125px;

     img {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          border-radius: 50%;
     }
}
```

[image: I am getting quite cropped it in the bottom]

I am getting it quite cropped in the bottom.
Are there any other solutions or what I am doing wrong in 2 examples above? Any help appreciate.

Comment: The second one is not valid CSS.

Comment: What is not working? Seems to be working to me assuming the second on is sass

Comment: Oh, I should have explain more briefly, I am actually using scss

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounded corners on rectangular image using CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267774/rounded-corners-on-rectangular-image-using-css-only)

Comment: Your image looks like it is the cause, not the css. Add a border to the image and see if it goes around.

Comment: your codes works fine : https://jsfiddle.net/Lt21nxwr/ (img)  or https://jsfiddle.net/h94k7a01/ (background) Please clarify , what is your svg ?

Comment: Your code looks fine and works when I tested it with my own image. I would say that it is either the image (not cropped maybe) or other code on the page is interfering with the image.

Comment: I assume the problem was with the image, I picked another one and it has worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some simple markup, a div container and the image is enough.

If the image may come in different sizes or shapes, you can use the [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property to make sure it displays correctly regardless. Just make sure you define the explicit size (height and width) you need the image to be, and then you can use `object-fit: cover` on the img itself so it maintains its aspect ratio and uses all available space for exmaple.

```css
.img-container {
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 200px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img.rect-img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="User photo">
</div>

<div class="img-container">
  <img class="rect-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" alt="User photo">
</div>
```

Comment: This answer helped me with the object-fit property:)

Answer (score 0):

It works without any problem. I think your image has some transparent parts.

```css
img {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

img.a {
  width: 64px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

img.b {
  width: 64px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Non-square image:</h1>
<img class="a" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579075475207-e59cd9d39be8">

<hr>

<h1>Converted to square using CSS:
  <h1/>
  <img class="b" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579075475207-e59cd9d39be8">
```