# How to convert an image to a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image

```
<input type="file" id="picture">
```

I would like to convert the image uploaded to the html input to a string. How can I do that using JavaScript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lookup `<canvas>` and *Base64* conversion.

Comment: Full HTML example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710147/image-convert-to-base64 that uses OP's method.

Answer (score 1):

Having

```
<input type="file" id="picture">
```

You can add an event handler to it listening to the change event (this code has to come after the above HTML or be registered on the `DOMContentLoaded` event)

```
var input = document.getElementById('picture');
input.addEventListener('change', handleFiles, false);
```

Then your `handleFiles` event would draw the image into a canvas and extract the base64 string from the file:

```
function handleFiles(e) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(base64);
  }

  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

Running example bellow:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('picture');
input.addEventListener('change', handleFiles, false);

function handleFiles(e) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById('result').value = base64;
  }

  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="picture" />
<br /> <br />
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

Comment: And then you've got a 300*150 image whatever the image size you passed. Also you've converted whatever the image was to an unoptimized png version.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a dataURI version, use a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Methods) and its `readAsDataURL()` method.

```js
file_input.onchange = function(e) {

  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function() {
    output.src = this.result;
  }
  fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file_input" />
<img id="output" />
```

If you just want to display it, then you can use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) Constructor :

```js
file_input.onchange = function(e) {

  output.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

};

// don't forget to revoke the URLObject when you don't need it anymore
output.onload = function() {
  URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file_input" />
<img id="output" />
```