# How to get base64 encoded string of an image in django?

Tags: python, django, base64

from html page user uploads a image, i want to convert it to base64 encoded string,
i am not using any forms, using just `<input type="file" name="galleryImage" class="filestyle" data-buttonText="Select a Image">`

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get why not using forms in Django, but for a static HTML you can try JS: 
[Image convert to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710147/image-convert-to-base64)