# Draw image inside object

Tags: javascript, object, drawimage

I have a bird={} object, and I want the bird object to have an image to represent it, but I need to have other properties inside the bird other than its image. How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: did you try something ?

Comment: I got there now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the following code to create a [HTML DOM Image Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp).

```
var bird = new Image();
bird.src = "http://www.ImageURL.png";
```

Comment: @MightySalmonStudiosLimited, glad to help! :)

Comment: @MightySalmonStudiosLimited, please make a new question with your issue so I can check it and try to help. That way you will get more attention from others too and at the same time, avoid editing and commenting to much here. (reply to your deleted comment)

Comment: It does not let me as this question was marked down by someone. would you mind answering if I send you an email or something?

Comment: @MightySalmonStudiosLimited, I upvoted to match (0). Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

you can use base64. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710147/image-convert-to-base64)

```
var bird = { IMAGE:"data-image/png;AAASFS..." }
```

Or you can keep image location like that;

```
var bird = { URL:"C:/Users/..../bird.png" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var bird =  {color: "blue", weight: 30, eyeColor:"#0000ff", imageSoure: "C:/Users/..../bird.png"};
```