# How do I read a user-specified file in an emscripten compiled library?

Tags: c, node.js, filesystems, emscripten

I'm currently working on a file parsing library in C with emscripten compile support. It takes a file path from the user where it reads the binary file and parses it.

I understand that emscripten doesn't support direct loading of files, but instead uses a virtual filesystem. Is there any way to load the file at the given path into the virtual filesystem so that the emscripten compiled C lib can read it? I'm looking for solutions for both NodeJS and in the browser.

Answer (score 14):

If you want compile this file directly into library you can use `--preload-file` or `--embed-file` option. Like this:

```
emcc main.cpp -o main.html --preload-file /tmp/my@/home/caiiiycuk/test.file
```

After that in C you can open this file normally:

```
fopen("/home/caiiiycuk/test.file", "rb")
```

Or you can use emscripten JavaScript [fs-api](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html), for example with AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/dataurl",
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        Module['FS_createDataFile']("/tmp", "test.file", data, true, true);
    }
});
```

After that you can open this file from C.
Also it is not best way to pass data into C code, you can pass data directly in memory, [read about this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emscripten-discuss/PeywyNHBbmY).

Answer (score 4):

If you can provide a file via a form upload from your webpage, then on receiving the file upload "data" you can do something like this.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978156/get-base64-encode-file-data-from-input-form) on how to achieve this

Sample code for your problem could be:

```
// Assuming data contains the base64 encoded fileData,
// you want the file to be present at "." location with name as myFileName
Module['FS_createDataFile'](".", myFileName, atob(data), true, true);
```

The detailed explanation of API used can be found [here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/advanced-apis.html#advanced-file-system-api)

This solution works for browsers where you do not have direct access to file system

Answer (score 3):

Emscripten, as of today (June 2016), supports a filesystem called `NODEFS` which provides access to the local file-system when running on `nodejs`.

You need to manually mount the `NODEFS` filesystem into the root filesystem. For example:

```
EM_ASM(
  FS.mkdir('/working');
  FS.mount(NODEFS, { root: '.' }, '/working');
);
```

You can then access `./abc` from the local filesystem via the virtual path `/working/abc`.

Comment: If you have a virtual filesystem library implementing node's fs api, is there a way to use your own virtual filesystem library instead of the provided NODEFS?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [synchronous virtual XHR backed file](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/files/Synchronous-Virtual-XHR-Backed-File-System-Usage.html). Beware that it requires that you execute your code in a web worker. If you want to support multiple files, you can access them using a virtual file system for an archive. The major plus of this approach is that it will defer loading until the file is actually read.