# ValueError: Data must not be a string

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to do the following with `requests`:

```
data = {'hello', 'goodbye'}
json_data = json.dumps(data)
headers = {
        'Access-Key': self.api_key,
        'Access-Signature': signature,
        'Access-Nonce': nonce,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'text/plain'
    }
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json_data, 
                 files={'file': open('/Users/david/Desktop/a.png', 'rb')})
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Data must not be a string.
```

Note that if I remove the `files` parameter, it works as needed. Why won't `requests` allow me to send a json-encoded string for data if `files` is included?

Note that if I change `data` to be just the normal python dictionary (and not a json-encoded string), the above works. So it seems that the issue is that if files is not json-encoded, then data cannot be json-encoded. However, I need to have my data encoded to match a hash signature that's being created by the API.

Comment: Have you tried `data=data`? (no json encoding)

Comment: Yes, but then it screws up the API signature (which every other method depends on).

Comment: You need to specify the header so that the module knows it's a JSON string. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-request) for details.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 -- no, that's not it. I already have those headers. It has to do with the data being passed is a string but the files being passed is not.

Comment: @David542 What is your header right now?

Comment: Just saw that you have specified a file; I don't think you can upload a file and use a JSON body at the same time.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 -- ok, thanks for that insight. How would I upload this file then? Send its data as a string?

Comment: @David542 Encapsulate your JSON string in a normal POST key-value pair (i.e "json" => json.dumps(data)).

Comment: Ok -- if I try putting that in my dict and doing `json` encoding I get a `UnicodeDecodeError` from the decoder though. It seems I can't encode this type of data in json?

Comment: Did you remove the `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you specify your body to a JSON string, you can no longer attach a file since file uploading requires the MIME type `multipart/form-data`.

You have two options:

1. Encapsulate your JSON string as part as the form data (something like `json => json.dumps(data)`)
2. Encode your file in Base64 and transmit it in the JSON request body. This [looks like a lot of work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978156/get-base64-encode-file-data-from-input-form) though.

Comment: Thanks, however when I try doing json.dumps with the image data, it returns a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Comment: Can someone please show example of such encapsulation suggested above by tyteen4a03?

Encapsulate your JSON string as part as the form data (something like json => json.dumps(data))

Comment: example needed pls

Answer (score 5):

1.Just remove the line
**json_data = json.dumps(data)**
and change in request as **data=data**.

2.Remove **'Content-Type': 'application/json'** inside headers.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

removing the following helped me in my case:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

then the data should be passed as dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to this problem is to post data as file.

1. You can post strings as files. Read more here:
   http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file
2. Here is explained how to post multiple files:
   http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files

Answer (score 0):

If your files are small, you could simply convert the binary (image or anything) to base64 string and send that as JSON to the API. That is much simpler and more straight forward than the suggested solutions. The currently accepted answer claims that is a lot of work, but it's really simple.

**Client:**

```
with open('/Users/houmie/Downloads/log.zip','rb') as f:
   bytes = f.read()
   tb = b64encode(bytes)
   tb_str = tb.decode('utf-8')
   body = {'logfile': tb_str}
   r = requests.post('https://prod/feedback', data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
```

**API:**

```
def create(event, context):
    data = json.loads(event["body"])
    if "logfile" in data:
        tb_back = data["logfile"].encode('utf-8')
        zip_data = base64.b64decode(tb_back)
```