# Python POST request doesn't receive post data from console but works fine on postman

Tags: python, postman

This is my postman call for the API and I am getting the needed response successfully.

P.S.: I have added the header: 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Here's the CURL generated by Postman:

```
curl --location 'api.example.com/apis/v2/show_user_reports' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --form 'token="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"' \ --form 'client_id="61"' \ --form 'user_id="7801"'
```

[image]

Now I am making an this API call using python 3.6 with same parameters and headers but it doesn't work:

```
url = 'https://api.example.com/apis/v2/show_user_reports'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data = {'token': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'client_id': '61', 'user_id': '7801'}

requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers).json()
```

By doing this, I am getting this response:

> {'error': 'Please Provide Client Id'}

Sure I am missing some small thing in this but couldn't find what.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED (previous answer was not correct)

Your `curl` is posting using `--form`, placing each parameter as an attachment. This is done by using `files` parameter in `requests.post`:

```
url = 'https://api.example.com/apis/v2/show_user_reports'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
files = {
    'token': (None, '"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"'),
    'client_id': (None, '"61"'),
    'user_id': (None, '"7801"'),
}
requests.post(url=url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

[Docs for multipart POST](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files)

The parameter attachments do not need a filename, so `None` is specified.

Comment: Already tried this, getting the same error "{'error': 'Please Provide Client Id'}"

Comment: Sorry, I missed a thing. I hope this should be correct now.

Comment: Sorry man, getting the same error again

Comment: Hmm, I see. The only difference is the boundary, which seems to get overwritten by adding the Content Type header, which sucks. Try if it will work without setting Content Type, which should give it the correct boundary but with `multipart/form-data`. If the server really wants `application/json`, then you will have to [construct the Content Type header and the body yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286656/python-set-up-boundary-for-post-using-multipart-form-data-with-requests) (making sure Content Type is as you wish).