# Python Requests - POST file with additional paramas

Tags: python, file, python-requests

So I have this code that send API request to upload a file to a server, after searching the web I came up with something like that where 'payload' is additional params I need to send and 'files' is a path to the file I want to upload :

```
def sendAPIRequest2(self, env, object, method, params, files):
    apiPath = "/api/secure/jsonws"
    headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    url = env + apiPath + object
    payload = {
        "method": method,
        "params": params,
        "jsonrpc": "2.0"
    }
    data = json.dumps(payload)
    myFile = {'file': open(files,'rb')}
    try:
        r = requests.post(url, files=myFile, data=data, headers=headers, 
                auth=HTTPBasicAuth(self.user, self.password), verify=False)
        print r.text
        resjson = json.loads(r.text)
    except:
        print "no Valid JSON has returned from"+object+" API"
        sys.exit(1)
    return resjson
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Data must not be a string.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations. ie. it shows which line makes problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: Data must not be a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553082/valueerror-data-must-not-be-a-string)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to me but why not use r.json() instead of json.loads(r.text)?

Comment: @Dan-Dev, can you explain the difference?

Comment: If there is a result r.json() will return a JSON object directly no need to get a text object and convert it to JSON.