# coldfusion - javascript image conversion

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have a form with an input[type=file].I need to read the image from that input into a variable/object.and possibly convert it into a base64 string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978156/get-base64-encode-file-data-from-input-form

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this with ColdFusion and return the Base64 to JS?

After uploading the image from your form:

```
<cfset imgObj = imageRead(imgFilePathWhereYouSavedTheUpload)>
<cfset binaryImage = toBase64(imgObj)>

<script>
<cfoutput>#ToScript(binaryImage, javascriptvar)#</cfoutput>
</script>
```