# How to convert an HTML <img> tag into a Base64 encoded image file?

Tags: javascript, html, base64

I have added CSS filters in the "**style**" attribute of an `<img>` tag containing an image.

```
<img src="myImage.png" style="filter: grayscale(100%)">
```

Now, the original image will look different due to the filters applied and I want that different looking image to be converted into Base64 image file using JavaScript.

Please help me out of this situation.

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978156/get-base64-encode-file-data-from-input-form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Base64 encode file-data from Input Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978156/get-base64-encode-file-data-from-input-form)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from HTML 5 You can use canvas for this.

Create a canvas element with your image. after that you can use the toDataURL method (returns a data URI containing the representation of the image in the format specified by the type parameter where the default format is image/png) in order to get the base64 image file.

you can read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL